# Good and compatible webcam to do image processing/computer vision?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, webcam

Please help. Rather than a actual question, this is a questions asking for feedback, suggestion and recommendation on what is a webcam good enough for image processing. I need a reasonable low light, self-focus camera that has enough depth of field to capture image.

Digital cameras are too bulky for use in my application and also need software to interface to an embedded processor, which I wish to avoid.

The image segmentation I am doing is quite tough in my opinion, requires edge detection, well defined images etc. Hence the image cannot be too noisy or "blur".

The camera I have in mind is  http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/hd-webcam-c310

Is this web-camera good enough in your opinion for image processing? Have anybody used it before? Thought the specifications look quite good, I have yet to test it.(It's difficult to find webcam on display which I can test)

Do anybody have any recommendations for such webcam or have a preferred webcam that you guys used for you own computer vision/image processing projects/applications? The budget that my school supervisor set for me is about USD$60 to 70. (Based on rough conversion of currency in my head)

Hope to hear you guys suggestion and recommendations soon. Any suggestion, recommendation is appreciated. Please help suggest. Thanks!

(P.S, I am using Windows 8. The various image processing tools that I use are MatLab and OpenCV with Visual Studio C++ 2010. Hence the webcam need to be compatible. i have found a list of what webcam are compatible for MatLab, but not openCV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the Logitech model you indicate. Is one megapixel (1280 x 720) resolution enough for you? Are you going to do video or stills only? The spec sheet on the website is light on details.

My recommendation is to take advantage of the return policy :-)  Order 10 different ones, get sample images with the same setup from all of them, pick the one that works best, return the other nine for full refund.

Comment: Oh. In addition, I can't seem to find the list of compatible cameras for OpenCV anywhere! Googled, clicked on links to it from other forums... The list just seem to have been removed. I presume logitech is compatible right? As it is supported by MatLab and is a rather common name in the industry.

Comment: That's a very good recommendation on the return policy. 1 megapixel resolution is a bit risky for me. The site claims that the webcam can take high resolution snapshots of up to 5 megapixel. Hence I am a little confused. I am presuming the (1280x720) resolution is for videos? I am doing stills for now. I am also looking at the C525 model. http://www.logitech.com/en-hk/product/7794.

Comment: I was assuming that 1MP is the native sensor resolution, given the "software enhanced" note on the higher resolution. But it may be somewhere in between. Remember also that pixel resolution is only one facet of image quality. The lens sharpness and noise figure matter a lot. A webcam's lens is, for example, optimized for subjects nearby and in a fairly wide FOV angle. You really ought to work backward from your application requirements to the camera you need - don't naively assume that software will patch over whatever garbage the camera is producing.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Learnt something new from you today. Thanks alot once again (: Really appreciate it alot!