# openCV compatible webcams

Tags: opencv, webcam

I have read that openCV does not recognise some webcams.

Can you suggest some webcams for a basic stereo-vision project using the following?:

- openCV 2.2.0
- Visual Studio 2010 (C++)
- Windows 7 32 bits

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I posted a similar question back then.

[Good and compatible webcam to do image processing/computer vision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873832/good-and-compatible-webcam-to-do-image-processing-computer-vision)

What kind of camera you are looking for? Any model? State the model and I let you know if it's good enough.

Also, you can find a list of compatible webcams with openCV. It's an old list though. They stopped updating it since 2013, I think. [Compatible webcam with openCV](https://web.archive.org/web/20120815172655/http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS/)

You find that most common brands like Hp, Logitech, etc should work just fine. If you are worried, just state the model you are looking at in the comments. I see if I know if it's compatible with openCV.

EDIT:

To answer your question in the comment, nope, that shouldn't be the case. All cameras can run simultaneously at the same time. Reasons that cameras can't run simultaneously at the same time is usually due to the USB bandwidth. In fact, most cameras pose the same problem.

Some methods to overcome that problem:
1)put a Sleep(ms) in between the lines of your capture line.
2)Use lower resolution which would reduce the bandwidth used by each camera.
3)Use MJPEG format(compressed frames)

Comment: OK, thank you. In my local store they have in stock the "Logitech C170". NOTE: I have read here [link] (http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/step_to_stereo_vision/) that Logitech cameras ussually present the issue that their "camera drivers don't allow/support viewing both cameras simultaneously".

Comment: @jaiserpe, I have updated my answer to answer your question about the viewing of cameras simultaneously. Do consider upvoting my answer if it is useful or accepting my answer if it works through the tick button under the arrows (: Cheers.